# How can I update my transitive dependency in maven?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-assembly-plugin

Lets say I have project P which has dependency on library A and A is depending on library B, so i found bug in B and want to update library by keeping same version of A library, one solution is exclude from A and add dependency again, but what I am looking is it should be done with in  tags.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not clear what you exactly mean by `..it should be done with in tags` ..otherwise you can simply add the dependency B in your pom directory with the newer version but of course it could that your build/test fail cause it is not the version A is depending on and if they are not compatible you might fail...

Answer (score 0):

P pom.xml

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>A</groupId>
            <artifactId>A</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>// this version comes with buggy B (version 1 for instance)
        <dependency>
            <groupId>B</groupId>
            <artifactId>B</artifactId>
            <version>2</version>// override the version coming from A
        </dependency>
```

BUT --> Be sure that A can  work with the new version of B....

Best solution -> FIX B --> Upgrade A with new B --> Upgrade A dependency in P

Comment: Actually I have a parent pom.xml, where A is main library and B is transitive library, when I do as mentioned above, I have to add entry in all child projects as <dependency>
            <groupId>B</groupId>
            <artifactId>B</artifactId>
            <version>2</version>//updated version
        </dependency>    ,....I want avoid this and do the modifications in parent pom.xml and changes should reflect in every child project

Comment: So? Why not redefine B dependency in parent ?

Comment: If you redefine B dependency in parent, all child projects has to include these changes right?

Comment: yes. If you don't want this you have to redefine the version in specific modules. Just avoid having coupled modules using different version of a library. It could cause severe problems at runtime